# What's the best pot size for rose seeds germinated in the refrigerator?

Tags: containers, seedlings, roses

I have taken rose seeds from my garden and put them in the fridge between moist paper towels.

Does anybody know what size pot I should put the rose seeds in that have germinated in the fridge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All plants should have pots matching the plant size, otherwise you risk root-bound plants or trouble with watering. That's why we re-pot as needed and only go up a few pot sizes at a time.

Roses like to go *deep* with their roots, so I would aim for a pot of ca. 5 cm / 2 inches height right now, once the seedling is established, take it from there.

Generally, roses prefer pots that are deeper than wide or, if those aren't available or feasible, let the height be the determining factor rather than width. If you want to keep them in pots permanently (And not all roses like that - especially with seeds from grafted plants you may be in for a few surprises!), they tolerate an undergrowth of shallow-rooted companion plants well to utilize the "extra width" in standard containers.

Comment: I'd start with the smallest pot I could, transplanting as the plant outgrows the pot...use only sterilized soil with added mycorhizzae  and bacteria for the potting soil.  No rocks at the bottom of pot...just fill pot with potting soil.  Deep roots are part of the height of your plant and watering practices, not dependent on pot depth.  Start small and as the roots begin coming through the bottom upgrade to a slightly larger pot.  Roses love CLAY pots that allow more air to their roots.  Once acclimated to the garden spot then perhaps some competition would be OK.